# Removing a NuGet package that isn't in my project?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I keep getting this warning in my VS2015 solution:

```
Some NuGet packages were installed using a target framework different from the current target framework and may need to be reinstalled.
```

The thing is, there are no NuGet packages in my solution. I had one, but I removed it, but I still get this.

Any ideas?

Comment: How was the packaged removed? If you manually edited the packages.config file, then there will be things left in your csproj. You should re-install the package, then uninstall with either the Package Manager UI or Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Removing a NuGet package that isn't in my project?

It seems that you have not properly removed that NuGet package.

To resolve this issue, please try to reinstall this package, then uninstall it.

**Detailed:**

Open the the Package Manager Console by `Tools`->`NuGet Packager Manager`->`Package Manager Console`, and type following command line to reinstall nuget package:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

After the re-installation is complete, type following command line to uninstall the package in the Package Manager Console:

```
Uninstall-Package <PackageID>
```

With this way, the nuget package will be moved from your project. If you have installed that package for multiple project in the solution, please use the uninstall command line for different default project in the Package Manager Console window:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Started off well... "Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2' already exists in project 'DLoader'", but then the next step "Uninstall-Package : Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2' to be uninstalled could not be found in project 'DCFLoader'" Is that the right ID?

Comment: Have you add the \packages folder into the source code? If yes, please remove it out.

Comment: Yay, that did it!

Comment: Well it's come back. Now I periodically see it "renewing nuget packages" and we're back to the start again.